# How to stop timer event when child form closes in MDI project

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm not a regular when it comes to windows forms but still getting better at C# in general. I'm developing a project for a comp. prog. class and it's an MDI form that allows multiple child forms.

Here's my pickle, 
I've got a timer on the parent form that; when ticking, handles two label methods ..one to count characters in a text document and the other to display a zoom level.

I can get the timer to fire and handle my events when a child windows opens but when I close the window, I am trying to figure out how to stop the timer some how.
I've tried the form.closing event and tried disabling the timer when I was done but this didn't help.

The project is a text editor and the object's name id "Document". When the object is Disposed, naturally I get an exception but I want to disable the timer before this happens.

"Cannot Access a Disposed Object"

Here's my New() method to call a an instance of a child form..

```
        void New()
      {
          // Generate a new form from scratch
          TextEditorChild = new Form();  // Declare a variable containing a new Form method
          TextEditorChild.Text = "Document " + count.ToString();  // Text Property - also gets the forms order number
          TextEditorChild.Icon = Properties.Resources._new_doc_icon;  // Use our own icon
          TextEditorChild.MdiParent = this;  // Ensure we are using the original form as the parent form
          Document = new RichTextBox();  // Call a new RichTextBox object
          Document.Multiline = true;  // Yes, a multiline textbox
          Document.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;  // Ensure that the textbox fills the new window
          TextEditorChild.Controls.Add(Document);  // Apply our controls to the child window
          TextEditorChild.Show();  // Display the window
          count++;  // Add this window to a potnetial list of windows, should multiple be opened all at once
          timer.Enabled = true;
      }
```

Here's my timer even handler...

```
       private void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            charCount.Text = "Characters in the current document: " + Document.TextLength.ToString();
            zoom.Text = Document.ZoomFactor.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Did you open more than one TextEditorChild or just one?

Comment: It throws the exception with just one. 
and actually, the code I posted wont allow the timer to begin at all.
My first stab was to create and IF statement and 
'
if (TextEditorChild == null)
{
return;
}
else
{
// the methods
}
'

This worked but when I close the child window, I got the message again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add

```
TextEditorChild.FormClosing += new FormClosingEventHandler(Close);
```

In the method new()

---

```
private void Close(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
{
    timer.Enabled = false;
}
```

And add this below, as a new method

---

This makes it so that when the form closes, it stops the timer, and then quits the form

Comment: That got it. 
I may have already tried something similar but I wasn't sure what type of arguments to use in the method. 
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Just prior to the line where you are enabling the timer add this code:

```
        var tec = TextEditorChild;
        FormClosingEventHandler closing = null;
        closing = (s, e) =>
        {
            tec.FormClosing -= closing;
            if (--count == 0)
            {
                timer.Enabled = false;
            }
        };
        tec.FormClosing += closing;
```

This should stop the timer when all of your windows are closed. I captured the module level `TextEditorChild` as `tec` to make sure the reference doesn't change when you open new child windows.

I assume that you are decrementing the `count` value elsewhere so you need to adjust your logic to make this work, but this should be a good start.

Comment: I couldnt get that method to work.
I like were your going with it though, as I had a similar idea to simply disable the timer when my child window count was down to zero.

Comment: I'll keep trying this method in different ways because that would be an ideal way for me to handle it as well.
I appreciate your input as well.

Comment: I tried the code just above the line were I enabled the timer but I still got the same exception when I closed a new child window.

Comment: @codeman061988 - I'd put a breakpoint on the `timer.Enabled = false` line and see if it is being called. If not then on the `tec.FormClosing -= closing` line to see if it is getting that far.

Comment: I played with that method for a bit this morning and I couldn't get to work when `(--count == 0)` . Interesting, when I change the operator to <= 1 , it will work on the first child menu but when I open and then close a second, I get my exception. Of course it is because I asked it to close at <= 1. I've tried other types of operators as well and I've tried using `< 1`.. ..I wonder if it only functions for the first instance. Although my `New()` method is for every new instance.